# Unit testing a service in Angular4

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, protractor, karma-jasmine

I'm fairly new to the world of Angular4 and using Jasmine/Karama for testing.  I've created a small app that wraps two web api services and I need to write tests for these.

Using online examples, and my basic understanding of mocking in Angular4, I've managed to hack together a test for my first service and its running fine.  The constructor of this first service has only one dependency (http module, which happened to coincide with the example I was using!).

**Service example 1** :

```
// Lookups api wrapper class.
@Injectable()
export class LookupsService {

    private servicegApiUrl = '';

    public constructor( private http : Http ) {  
        // Build the service api url, uring the environment lookups api url, plus controller name to reference.
        this.servicegApiUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'Lookups/';
    }

    // Get the hubs from the web api.
    public getHubs() : Observable<KeyValuePair<number>[]> {
        // Carry out http get and map the result to the KeyValuePair number object.
        return this.http.get(this.servicegApiUrl + 'Hubs').map(res => { 
            if (res){ return res.json() as KeyValuePair<number>[]; }
        });
    }
}
```

*Tests example 1 - Tests working:*

```
describe('Service: LookupService', () => {

  let service: LookupsService;
  let backend: MockBackend;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
        LookupsService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        }
      ]
    });

    // Get the MockBackend
    backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);

    // Returns a service with the MockBackend so we can test with dummy responses
    service = TestBed.get(LookupsService);

  });

  it('getHubs() should return populated KeyValuePair<number>[]', async(() => {
    let response = 
        [{
            "Key": "Hub 1 example",
            "Value": 1
        },{
            "Key": "Hub 2 example",
            "Value": 2
        }]
    ;

    // When the request subscribes for results on a connection, return a fake response
    backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(<ResponseOptions>{
        body: JSON.stringify(response)
      }));
    });

    // Perform a request and make sure we get the response we expect
    var hubsRes : KeyValuePair<number>[];
    service.getHubs().subscribe(hubs => { 
        hubsRes = hubs;
        console.log(hubs);
    });

    // Test hubs is populated.
    expect(hubsRes.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);

  }));

});
```

All good so far, I now need to write tests for a second service.  In this service I had injected a custom service I created for logging (it doesn't have any dependencies injected in, and simply wraps console.log).

**Service example 2**

```
// Routing Rules api wrapper class.
@Injectable()
export class RoutingRulesService {

    private servicegApiUrl = '';

    public constructor( private loggerService : LoggerService, private http : Http ) {  
        // Build the service api url, uring the environment routing api url, plus controller name to reference.
        this.servicegApiUrl = environment.routingApiUrl + 'routingRules/';
    }

    // Perform search using passed in filter.  Returns SearchResult object.
    public getSearchFiltered(options): Observable<SearchResult> {
        // Api url is the service url, plus Filtered and search query string.
        var apiUrl = this.servicegApiUrl + 'Filtered' + options;
        this.loggerService.logInfo("Route search query url: " + apiUrl);

        // Carry out http get and map the result to the SearchResult object.
        return this.http.get(apiUrl).map(res => { 
            if (res){ return res.json() as SearchResult; }
        });
    }
}
```

*Tests example 2 - Tests **not working**:*

```
describe('Service: RoutingRulesService', () => {

  let service: RoutingRulesService;
  let logger : LoggerService;
  let backend: MockBackend;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule, LoggerService],
      providers: [
        RoutingRulesService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },
        logger
      ]
    });

    // Get the MockBackend
    backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);

    // Returns a service with the MockBackend so we can test with dummy responses
    service = TestBed.get(RoutingRulesService);

  });

  it('getSearchFiltered(), with no search parameter, should return populated SearchResult', async(() => {
    let response = 
    {
      "Pagination": {
        "RecordCount": 2,
        "PageRecordsFrom": 1,
        "PageRecordsTo": 1,
        "TotalPages": 1,
        "PageSize": 2,
        "PageNumber": 1,
        "SortBy": "RoutingRuleId",
        "Ascending": true
      },
      "Results": [
        {
          "RoutingRuleId": 1,
          "BrandId": 21,
          "CashOnDelivery": false,
          "CreationTime": "2017-09-11T15:14:41.207",
          "CurrencyCode": 2,
          "CurrencyDescription": "USD"
        },
        {
          "RoutingRuleId": 2,
          "BrandId": 21,
          "CashOnDelivery": false,
          "CreationTime": "2017-09-11T15:14:41.207",
          "CurrencyCode": 2,
          "CurrencyDescription": "USD"
        }]
      }    
    ;

    // When the request subscribes for results on a connection, return a fake response
    backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(<ResponseOptions>{
        body: JSON.stringify(response)
      }));
    });

    // Perform a request and make sure we get the response we expect
    var searchRes : SearchResult;
    service.getSearchFiltered(null).subscribe(results => { 
        searchRes = results;
        console.log(results);
    });

    // Test populated.
    expect(searchRes.Pagination.RecordCount).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    expect(searchRes.Results[0].RoutingRuleId).toEqual(1);

  }));
});
```

I get this error when compiling my tests:

*Service: RoutingRulesService getSearchFiltered(), with no search parameter, should return populated SearchResult FAILED
        Error: Unexpected value 'LoggerService' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.*

How do I successfully inject a new instance of my logger service into this second service?

Thanks for all pointers in advance!

Comment: The error message says it all: you've added LoggerService to the imports og your testing module instead of adding it to its providers.

Comment: I strongly suggest you switch to the HttpClient service instead of the old, soon deprecated Http service. It'll make things much easier to test, too.

Comment: Ahh, very simple fix!  Thanks for that!  Also, switched to HttpClient instead of Http, thanks @JBNizet!